# Tablesorter sortList Malfunction?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

Tablesorter sortList Malfunction?

why cannot i set an initial column sort order with sortList?

```
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    sortList : [[4,1]], // initial sort columns (2nd and 3rd)
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[[4,1]]` will sort the 5th column (it uses a zero-base index).

Instead try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/34/)):

```
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({
    sortList : [[1,1],[2,1]], // initial sort columns (2nd and 3rd)
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
  });
});
```